# xUnit doesn't run on Azure DevOps CI pipline

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, xunit, vstest

I am trying to run xUnit tests using the Azure CI pipeline, despite the unit tests running successfully in Visual Studio 2017, but on Azure DevOps no results. Below are screenshots  for the vs solution and build and test tasks in the Azure pipeline: '

**Test project**

[image]

**The solution in the visual studio**

[image: Solution]

**The solution in the pipeline**

[image: Solution in the CI pipline]

**Build task**

[image: Build task]

**Test task**

[image: test task]

**Test task results**

[image]

What is the problem with my setup?

Comment: Did you added package `xunit.runner.visualstudio` to your test project?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej yes. please check my question edit.

Comment: Hi Adham, is there any update for this issue?  Can `**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\UnitTesting.dll` from **Krzysztof Madej**'s answer helps to resolve your issue? In my test, it works well to find the required assembly. And according to your error message, you're trying `*\bin\release**\UnitTesting.dll` instead of recommended `**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\UnitTesting.dll`.

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT. Unfortunately not.
I am using: **\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\UnitTesting.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your test files and replace this line:

```
**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*test*.dll
```

with this:

```
**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\UnitTesting.dll
```

or this:

```
**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\UnitTesting.dll
```

Please try to apply this pattern to your folder structure in you bin folder.

Comment: I got this error:
##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\bin\release\UnitTesting.dll,!**\obj\**,!**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll,!**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll.

Comment: I don't see any error, but can you paste a path to your UnitTesting.dll (from your computer)?

Comment: Did you try this? `**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\UnitTesting.dll`

Comment: yes with this message: ##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\bin\release\**\UnitTesting.dll,!**\obj\**,!**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll,!**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll.

Comment: You missed slash after release.

Comment: Hi @Krzysztof Madej. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @AdhamEnaya do you still have this issue?